# Recover Multibit password: brute-force

Tags: multibit

I misprint 1 symbol in the password.
Now I want to brute-force it.

I may write a simple script that will brute-force every symbol.
Is there any way to check the password from the command line? May be in different bitcoin client?

Comment: You can certainly write a Java program that will attempt Multibit decryption and report back if it succeeds or not, since Multibit is open-source. If you want help with this, please let me know (contact info is available on my Bitcoin Stack Exchange profile).